# Event when Data is loaded in Content Pane

Tags: dojo, dijit.layout

I have a dijit.layout.contentPane defined as :

```
<div dojoAttachPoint="X_containerInternal" dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" splitter="true" region="center" gutters="true" >
               <div dojoAttachPoint="X_objectDetail" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="left" splitter="true"
                   style="width:50%;">
               </div>
               <div dojoAttachPoint="X_documentDetail" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center" splitter="true">
               </div>
           </div>
```

When the loading starts I have added a load Icon and when the data is placed in X_documentDetail(dojoattachpoint) I want to hide the load Icon but I am not getting event which is called when the loading is complete which can be specified in the attachevent.

Please guide.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
dojo.connect(_container_, "onLoad", function(){ /* your script */});
```